# Assigning variables to elements of nested ngRepeats [ANGULAR]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

In my app I have articles that have comments. My problem is that I am unable to update the comments scope whenever I add/edit/delete a comment. I want it to be dynamic, so that the comments scope updates without the need for a page refresh. I am using ngResource to make queries for comments and articles. (e.g. `$scope.articles = newsService.query())`

This is my structure

```
ng-repeat="article in articles"
  ng-repeat="comment in article.comments"
```

What is a good pracitce, general solution to update the comments scope of an article when a comment is added/deleted/modified?

NOTE: The comments in article.comments are references to comments. Each comment has a reference to an article.

Comment: Where is the rest of your code?  If you have a model associated with the comment, 2-way binding should make the comment update when it is modified.  Added and deleted means you will have to do an update on the object/array.  I would need to see more code in order to assist you any further.

Comment: Why not just make a article class, then have an array of 'article' objects? You can then easily delete or add comments to a single object and that should update well with Angular.

Comment: Mostly because I am new, I am probably going about all of this in the wrong way. There is not more code since I wanted the answer to be general, and because there is so much code involved I couldn't figure out how to fit it all into a question without writing a book. I apologize if I am not making myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your ng-repeats looks fine. What looks to be problemmatic is how you are fetching the service data and assigning it to the `$scope` variable: `$scope.articles = newsService.query()`. Because fetching data using ngResource is an asynchronous process, the assignment of articles needs to be handled using promises.

Your `query` method should be returning a promise so that you can provide a success handler and set the `$scope` variable once the data has been retrieved. Assuming your `query` method is already returning a promise, you should be able to do the following:

```
newsService.query().then(function(resp) {
    $scope.articles = resp.data;
});
```

If the above does not work, please post the implementation of the `query` method.